# Check in what range is a number

Tags: php

I have a random number from 0 to 100 (x) and different ranges. How to check in which range the number is?

Example:

Given

```
Case1 (0 - 40),
Case2 (40 - 60),
Case3 (60 - 75),
Case4 (75 - 85),
Case5 (85 - 100)
```

and `x = 50`, the result should be `Case2`.

Comment: `if (number >= rangeStart and number <= rangeEnd)`. This is __math__, not programming.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! But i'm searching for another solution .

Comment: What other solution do you expect?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific solution, or is there something you have not included in your question?

Comment: if you want it to be dynamic, you could put the end of each range in an array like `[40, 60, 75, 85, 100]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example on how to check which range a given number belongs to. Define an associative ranges array, where cases are keys and bottom limits are key values. Then loop the array through and compare the given number to the limits. If the number equals or is bigger than the limit, return the limit's case.

```
$range = in_which_range( rand(0,100) );

function in_which_range( int $number ) {
  foreach ( ranges() as $case => $bottom_limit ) {
    if ( $number >= $bottom_limit ) {
      return $case;
    }
  }
}

function ranges() {
  return array(
    'case5' => 85,
    'case4' => 75,
    'case3' => 60,
    'case2' => 40,
    'case1' => 0,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have 5 ranges:

- Range #0: 0-40
- Range #1: 41-60 (note that this range starts from 41, not from 40; otherwise you will get *intersecting* ranges that's probably not what you originally wanted)
- Range #2: 61-75
- Range #3: 76-85
- Range #4: 86-100

You can store your ranges in a single array, just put there all range borders sorted.

```php
$ranges = [0, 40, 60, 75, 85, 100];
```

Note that you have 5 ranges, but 6 elements in array - that's important. Now you can easily check for each range:

```php
$findRange = function(int $x, int ...$ranges): ?int
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($ranges) - 1; $i++) {
        $start = 0 == $i ? $ranges[$i] : $ranges[$i] + 1;
        $end = $ranges[$i + 1];
        if ($x >= $start && $x <= $end) {
           return $i;
        }
    }

    return null;
};

foreach ([0, 41, 86, 101] as $x) {
    $range = $findRange($x, ...$ranges);
    $message = null === $range
        ? "Value {$x} is not in the range"
        : "Value {$x} is in range #{$range}";
    echo $message, PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will output:

```
Value 0 is in range #0
Value 41 is in range #1
Value 86 is in range #4
Value 101 is not in the range
```

Here is [the working demo](https://3v4l.org/os4IS).